# Breaking the SQL Compact 8K Limit?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce, binary-data

I am creating a desktop application that stores rich text documents to a SQL Compact database. Documents are converted to a byte array and stored as a Binary column, and I am running into SQL Compact's 8K limit for Binary field length.

Is there a simple way to get around the 8K limit? I can come up with lots of complicated ways to do it, such as parsing into 8K chunks for storage and reassembling on fetch. But before I get into something that complex, I would like to make sure I can't solve the problem more simply, such as by changing data type.

If there is no simple way of getting around the 8K limit, is thare a best practice for storing documents greater than 8K? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is there a special reason to store files in the database, not in the file system?

Comment: Good point--I could store docs in the file system. The app tags documents (similar to blog), so DB is needed. But db could store relative paths to docs, rather than docs themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd use [image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172424.aspx) data type, no?

Comment: That will only work until he runs into the 1,073,741,823 byte limit.

Comment: ROFL--thanks for saving me a lot of work! I *think* a gigabyte should be sufficient to hold a document! I am using Entity Framework 4, so I'll need to verify that the Image data type will work. But you answered the question that I ask, so it gets my acceptance!